# Dividend policy in terms of net profit or free cash flow?

Tags: corporate-finance

Is dividend policy usually formulated in terms of net profit or free cash flow (to equity)? Simplifying, which one would be more common:

> Pay out 50% of net profit for the year/quarter

or

> Pay out 50% of free cash flow (to equity) for the year/quarter

?